# Check if a MySql database has been updated in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to detect whether a MySql database has been updated the second it has been updated. So far I've just found triggers but it, https://www.siteground.com/kb/mysql-triggers-use/, said I need superuser privileges and, unfortunately, the domain I use is a shared server.

So currently there is one group working on inserting all user information into the database like so.

```
<form method="post">
-> user post data
</form>
<?php
-> post data to varibles, $x $y as examples

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "user";
    $password = "pass";
    $dbname = "name";

    // Check connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if(!$conn){
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO Test (Col1, Col2)
    VALUES (". $x .",". $y .")";

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

And then my group, in a separate file, is supposed to get the data from the database when it is updated. Our file set up looks like this.

```
<?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "user";
    $password = "pass";
    $dbname = "name";

    // Check connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if(!$conn){
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    ->trigger on column update

    $sql = "SELECT Col1, Col2, time FROM Test";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    ->etc.

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

So far I've only found triggers that are in MySql but there doesn't seem to be a way to directly do it in PHP ex.

```
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER agecheck BEFORE INSERT ON people FOR EACH ROW;
```

Comment: Does this help? https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/mysql-after-insert-trigger/

Comment: you could use a [on update timestamp](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html) perhaps so PHP can then sample table rows ordered by last update?

Comment: I don't know how to use MySQL language besides the basic adminer interface, and on top of that, codetasty doesn't seem to support the language. Please correct me if so.